# Value of the php variable fetched from mysql database cannot display in bootstrap modal

Tags: php, mysql, html, html-table, bootstrap-modal

I would to fetch the mysql database table rows and display it into the html tables after that when user click on the value in table, bootstrap modal trigger and display all the column values of that clicked row in modal.
Here is php code

```
  <tbody>
               <?php
                include "connection.php";
                $sql="SELECT email,date_t from users";
                $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                  $mail=$row['email'];
                  $getID = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT fname,email from users where email='$mail'"));
                  $fname = $getID['fname'];
                  $email = $getID['email'];
                  echo '<tr>
                  <td>'.$fname.'</td>
                  <td><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mymodel">'.$row['email'].'</a></td>
                  <td>'. "$email" .'</td>
                  <td>'.$row['date_t'].'</td>
                  </tr>';
                } 

                ?>

  </tbody>
```

Here is bootstrap modal

```
    <div id="mymodel" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Email Reply</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p><?php echo $email; echo $fname; ?></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**It will display value of $fname in modal but not display the value of $email**

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Where do you expect the modal to get the values for a particular row? It can't be from the php code since that runs on the server when the page is generated. You'll either need to use JS and an array with the values from all of the rows to populate the modal before display, or use AJAX to get the data for a particular row.

Comment: modal should display the value of that particular click row. I use the anchor tag in <td> to trigger modal

Comment: Everything works fine it also display the value of $fname in modal but not display the value of $email why?

Comment: multiple rows in the table, with only `data-toggle`, should be impossible to send data from any row to the modal. only one row would work, maybe the last row

Comment: `why not display the value of $email`? debug the `$email` value from the DB.

Comment: `Everything works fine it also display the value of $fname`, if so, there must be more code in addition to the code shown in your question?